# Call .net core controller get method with an object from angular2

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have a angular component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';


@Component({
    selector: 'search',
    template: require('./search.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./search.component.css')]
})
export class SearchComponent {
    public tumorType = "Tymor Type";
    public gene = "Gene";
    public searchList: any[];
    public searchCriteria:
        {
            TumorType: string;
            Gene: string;
            Country: string;
        } =
        {
            TumorType: "Acute Lymphoblastic Leukemia",
            Gene: "ABL",
            Country: "Australia"
        };

    constructor(private http: Http) {

    }

    public search() {
        let searchCrit = this.searchCriteria; 
        this.http.get('/api/RocheClinicalTrial/' + JSON.stringify({ searchCrit })).subscribe(result => {
            //this.searchList = result.json();
            console.log(result);
        });

    }
}
```

and a mvc controller

```
namespace RocheClinicalTrial.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class RocheClinicalTrialController : Controller
    {
        // GET: api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get()
        {
            var repo = new Repository.Repository();
            var data = repo.GetData();

            return Json(data);
        }

        [Route("GetData")]
        //GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("api/values")]
        public string Get(string searchCriteria)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(searchCriteria);
            return "value";
        }
}
}
```

This should call the

> Get(string searchCriteria)

method. But the call isn't happening. But when I call without value

> this.http.get('/api/RocheClinicalTrial/' /*+ JSON.stringify({
>   searchCrit })*/).subscribe(result => {
>               //this.searchList = result.json();
>               console.log(result);
>           });

it calls the

> public JsonResult Get()

method. Can you please help.

Here is the call screenshot from network tab

[image]

Comment: have you checked network tab ? to see what and where request went ..?

Comment: Yes I did. It calls " http://localhost:52086/api/RocheClinicalTrial/%7B%22searchCrit%22:%7B%22TumorType%22:%22Acute%20Lymphoblastic%20Leukemia%22,%22Gene%22:%22ABL%22,%22Country%22:%22Australia%22%7D%7D "
even if i direct hit url localhost:52086/api/RocheClinicalTrial/something . The call doesn't go there.

Comment: try to console the whole request url and see what is the dirrence

Comment: can you share screenshot of the network tab details ?

Comment: that mens issue with ur controller method as Isee unhave some route parameter on get method

Comment: I have added the screenshot. I don;t think it's an issue with the searchCriteria  binding. Because even if i call with a normal string value, the call doesn't go to the controller action.

Comment: your issue is with the cntroller method [Route("GetData")]
        //GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("api/values")]
        public string Get(string searchCriteria){}

Answer (score 3):

I'm a tad confused on what is the goal here. I see two possible api url possibilities here.

Number 1:

```
api/RocheClinicalTrial?searchCriteria=yourSearchCriteria
```

For this, the current sample "should" work. But you need to use just one action and make sure the query parameter searchCriteria is not null or empty.

```
namespace RocheClinicalTrial.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class RocheClinicalTrialController : Controller
    {
        // GET: api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get(string searchCriteria)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchCriteria))
            {
                var repo = new Repository.Repository();
                var data = repo.GetData();

                return Json(data);
            }
            // Return back full payload.
        }
    }
}
```

Number 2: The one that was intended in the Angular 2 component

```
api/RocheClinicalTrial/yourSearchCriteria
```

Something like the following would be sufficient

```
namespace RocheClinicalTrial.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class RocheClinicalTrialController : Controller
    {
        // GET: api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get()
        {
            var repo = new Repository.Repository();
            var data = repo.GetData();

            return Json(data);
        }

        [HttpGet("{searchCriteria}")]
        public string Get(string searchCriteria)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(searchCriteria);
            return "value";
        }
    }
}
```

Now, a gentle reminder here. A url length is finite, according to IE it is 2,083 characters. It might roam around the same region for other browsers and clients.

To send back a proper json payload, it is always better to use a POST.

Something like the following would be of use then:

```
namespace TestApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get()
        {
            var data = "I'm the default one";
            return Json(data);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Get([FromBody] SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
        {
            return new ObjectResult(searchCriteria);
        }
    }
}
```

A sample post request from Angular 2 would be:

```
  public search() {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        let searchCrit = this.searchCriteria; 
        this.http.post('/api/RocheClinicalTrial/', searchCrit, options)
             .subscribe(result => {
                 console.log(result);
             });

    }
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to decorate a controller Get method with [HttpPost]? Are there any security vulnerabilities associated with this? Seems counterintuitive.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to bind the search criteria then modify your api url so it looks like this :

`api/RocheClinicalTrial?searchCriteria=yourSearchCriteria`

you need to do this if you haven't specified an MVC route to match this.
so basically the extra paramater matches the same thing on the MVC side and then the MVC engine can automatically map that value for you.

It also means you will have to URL encode your search string otherwise you might have an invalid URL.

If I were you I would not use a GET for this method, use a POST and pass the data inside it. Don't forget URLs have a character limit so you can't make them too long

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

Here is my call from client side:

```
    this.http.get('/api/RocheClinicalTrial/Details/' + this.searchCriteria).subscribe(result => {
        //this.searchList = result.json();
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Here is my controller:

```
namespace RocheClinicalTrial.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/RocheClinicalTrial")]
    public class RocheClinicalTrialController : Controller
    {
        // GET: api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get()
        {
            var repo = new Repository.Repository();
            var data = repo.GetData();

            return Json(data);
        }

        [Route("Details/{ItemName}")]
        //GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("api/values")]
        public string Get(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(searchCriteria);
            return "value";
        }
}
}
```